# QGIS Python Error by preprocessing tool (clip multiple rasters) with Semi automatic classification plugin

Tags: qgis, python, scp

I'm trying to convert Landsat 8 satellite images the SCP Plugin in QGIS. Turned out that I didn't come that far. I have major issues with everything (I guess it's because I'm using a mac);

I want to clip multiple rasters (the preprocessing tool of SCP) but I instantly get a python error; maybe someone has an idea what the error is about. I'm very new to this topic.

```
2022-03-24T19:41:14     WARNING    warning:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:96: UserWarning: resource_tracker: process died unexpectedly, relaunching. Some resources might leak.
              warnings.warn('resource_tracker: process died unexpectedly, '
         
     traceback: File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/threading.py", line 912, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/threading.py", line 892, in run
      self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 513, in _handle_workers
      cls._maintain_pool(ctx, Process, processes, pool, inqueue,
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 337, in _maintain_pool
      Pool._repopulate_pool_static(ctx, Process, processes, pool,
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
      w.start()
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
      self._popen = self._Popen(self)
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
      return Popen(process_obj)
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
      super().__init__(process_obj)
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
      self._launch(process_obj)
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 40, in _launch
      tracker_fd = resource_tracker.getfd()
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py", line 67, in getfd
      self.ensure_running()
      File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py", line 96, in ensure_running
      warnings.warn('resource_tracker: process died unexpectedly, '
```